# Interfaces are not enough for the object behind them to work?

Tags: java, interface

I've got an interface MigrateScenario with its methods. I also have its implementation MigrateScenarioImpl. The instance of MigrateScenarioImpl is being serialized and then passed as a byte[] to some web-service. On the service side, when I try to  do this:

```
Object obj = (new ObjectInputStream(digitalObject.getContent().getInputStream())).readObject();
MigrateScenario mgrScenario = (MigrateScenario) obj;
```

and what I get is that MigrateScenarioImpl class is missing in the classpath. The obj variable contains that object and the interface should blindly ask for the corresponding methods, since the object "knows itself" how to execute them. However, when I add the MigrateScenarioImpl to the classpath, then all works fine. Am I missing something here?
Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I don't use Java, but similar code in .NET simply works.  Not sure what you are doing wrong...

Comment: @merlyn I wouldn't be surprised if .NET was sending across the implementation as well as the object. Just sounds like something it would do.

Comment: @glowcoder, John_Doe: Actually I'm wrong.  I was thinking within the same application...  Across service boundaries, you lose all implementation information, so I wouldn't expect this to work in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't deserialize a class without having that class known to the classloader (e.g. by being on the classpath).  The code for the class itself is not serialized, it is expected to be known on the other end.

Comment: That's right, it saves the fields, but not the code. So no way it is known on the other end how to readObject. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing just the interface doesn't help the JVM know what to do. It needs the `Impl` to know what to actually do, not just what methods are available.

Comment: Yes you need impl classes on both sides. I can't speak for other languages, sorry :-(

Answer (score 1):

When you deserialize the object, Java needs to instantiate and initialize in an instance of the class.  Interfaces cannot be instantiated, so Java must instantiate the implementation class.  The serialization of a class contains instance data (the values of non transient instance variables), not the code of implemented methods, so there are no methods for the interface to point to.